# How to upload shapefile as input to geoprocessing service using javascript api

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

I need to pass a shapefile as input to my geoprocessing service so as to perform extra process with the features included in it?
 The geoprocessing service will be called from the clients web page using the javascript api. I am using arcgis 10.2.2
Is that feasible ?  If yes are there any examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes, this is feasible.
2. yes, here is an example:
   https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html

rather than esriRequest, you will need to pass the zipped file as one of your inputParameters when calling Geoprocessor.[execute()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geoprocessor-amd.html#execute)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @John Gravois. Considering that I want to use the uploaded shapefile as an input to a tool inside the toolbox. How could use the uploaded file ? What should I do inside the toolbox? I cannot find any example of doing this.

Comment: it depends on lots of factors.  (for example, are you writing a python script or using Model Builder?) for starters, see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_creating_tools_with_ModelBuilder/00150000001t000000/ for a general discussion on defining model parameters and  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Advanced_properties/0057000000m1000000/ESRI_SECTION1_F4ACDF122AF248B48075C171E265D3F2/ for information on file uploads.